# Oracle Connection request timed out after publish in C#

Tags: c#, database, oracle, asp.net-core

Firstly I should say that there are a lot of problems with the same title. I read them all. My problem is a bit different.

When I run my project from VS 2019 in my pc, it works perfect and list data I want. But after I publish my project and run from browser there is an error : `Connection request timed out`

I setup VS2019 in server machine and run it in local and add an debug point. The error happens at 
`con.Open()` line

```
  OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection { ConnectionString = connectionString };
  con.Open(); // Error's line
```

What should I do to solve this problem...

---

EDİT 1:
About 30-40 mins ago I tried and this time website work rightly... I didn't do anything... But now the error occurs...

As I see it's not about code or server. So what is the main problem?

---

EDİT 2:
I add 
`Connection Timeout=900;` to my connectionString. This time I got 
`ORA-03135: Connection lost contact` error :)

Comment: check the network connection, firewall, and server configuration of your database

Comment: What content has the exception?

Comment: Is the Oracle configuration (sqlnet.ora, ldap.ora...) identical on both machines?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I can reach the database from toad. The server is remote, I reach it with its IP address and port. On the other hand my project works in my pc (VS2019). When we control firewall and server configuration we couldn't find any issues...

Comment: @vc74 of course

Comment: Check the response of `tnsping` to remote db from your pc

Answer (score 0):

Check that your published server has access (port/ ip) to your Oracle database. may be that is the reason

Comment: The server accessed the database. There must another reason... By the way. About 30 min ago I tried again and it work but now again it show me error message... I think main reason is not about coding or server... But what?

Comment: what do you mean by server has access to oracle? does oracle run on same server?

Comment: No. I run project in VS2019 in server and it work fine for once. Oracle is in another server. So I know that my project can reach the database, but not everytime....